# Connecting a flask container to a redis container over kubernetes

Tags: docker, flask, kubernetes, redis

I've just setup a redis instance however I can't seem to get the two containers to talk to each-other, the setupworks over local machine with docker-compose but does not seem to be working with kubernetes.

My logs tell me flask can't find the service, so the error must be my configuration files

## Flask code:

```py
rDB = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379, db=0)
```

## Flask server:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dashboard
  namespace: default
  labels:
    run: dashboard
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: dashboard
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: dashboard
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/******/dashboard_server:v102
        name: dashboard
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 8000
          initialDelaySeconds: 300
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 300
          failureThreshold: 3
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
            name: http
            protocol: TCP
```

## Redis instance:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1 #  for k8s versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2  and before 1.8.0 use extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: dashboard
      role: master
      tier: backend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: dashboard
        role: master
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis  # or just image: redis
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
```

## Service code

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dash-service
  namespace: default
  labels:
    run: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    run: dashboard
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8000
  type: ClusterIP
```

Comment: You are missing a very important part of K8S : the `Service`. This is what you need to enable connections on your redis pod(s). You have to create a Service (NodePort or ClusterIP) "on top" of redis, so your flask app can access redis through that service.

Comment: @Flo sorry forgot to include my service! please see my edits

Comment: Ok I see. In docker compose you can pass the name of the container as "host" , but not with k8s. In k8s you have to reference the service. Can you try that host in your flask app instead: `<redis-service-name>.default.svc.cluster.local` ?

Comment: By the way, the service you added is the flask service. You also have to create a service for Redis so your flask pods that access Redis pods.

Comment: @Flo will that command work despite not having a service setup for the redis container

Comment: No, while you don't have a service which points to Redis, the pods can't be accessed. I'll post a sample service decalration for redis in few seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a service I created my redis cluster inside k8s.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: redis
  name: my-redis-svc
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: redis
    port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: redis
  type: ClusterIP
```

If you create that service. Your pods should be accessible by other pods in same namespace using that hostname :

```
my-redis-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
```

That means, in your app code you have change that line :

```py
rDB = redis.Redis(host='my-redis-svc.default.svc.cluster.local', port=6379, db=0)
```

Comment: thank you! should I edit my redis configuration file to match the selector / labels defined in that service?

Comment: The important thing is the `selector.app` that has to match the app name as you wrote in your deployment's `metadata.name` (which is redis so that should be fine).