# Connect Flask python script to Redis in K8s cluster

Tags: flask, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, redis

I have k8s cluster in ec2, I have implemented the guestbook k8s (php and redis) example and it works well.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/guestbook/

I have a flask app, it's a docker image. This app has main.py script file and inside it, I have tried connecting Redis with the following help
[Connecting a flask container to a redis container over kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60530063/connecting-a-flask-container-to-a-redis-container-over-kubernetes)

this is my redis service running in EC2

```
redis-follower      ClusterIP      10.102.44.232    <none>        6379/TCP         16d
redis-leader        ClusterIP      10.108.164.219   <none>        6379/TCP         16d
```

this is my python script

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
import os
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis, RedisError
import socket





app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")

def sample_run_report():


    redis_conn = Redis(host='redis-leader.default.svc.cluster.local', port=6379, db=0)
    redis_conn.set("key", "foo")
    val = redis_conn.get("key")
    return val




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I dont get the value, I think my connection to Redis is not successful.

For deployments I have used guestbook php redis yaml.
[application/guestbook/redis-leader-deployment.yaml](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/guestbook/)

```
# SOURCE: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/guestbook

apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: Deployment

metadata:

  name: redis-leader

  labels:

    app: redis

    role: leader

    tier: backend

spec:

  replicas: 1

  selector:

    matchLabels:

      app: redis

  template:

    metadata:

      labels:

        app: redis

        role: leader

        tier: backend

    spec:

      containers:

      - name: leader

        image: "docker.io/redis:6.0.5"

        resources:

          requests:

            cpu: 100m

            memory: 100Mi

        ports:

        - containerPort: 6379
```

This is the service and deployment YAML file I use for flask app deployment in ec2.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-flask-python1-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: redis-flask-python1
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 6000
      targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-flask-python1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis-flask-python1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis-flask-python1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis-flask-python1
          image: http://docker.io/dechenw/redis-flask-python1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: seems like you did not create the service for redis? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/guestbook/#creating-the-redis-leader-service

Comment: I did, I have redis-leader and redis-follower services.

Comment: are you able to see `kubectl get service` in default ns?

Comment: Yes, this is the output
NAMESPACE     NAME                          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE


default       redis-flask-python1-service   LoadBalancer   10.98.247.229    <pending>     6000:31083/TCP           139m
default       redis-follower                ClusterIP      10.102.44.232    <none>        6379/TCP                 16d
default       redis-leader                  ClusterIP      10.108.164.219   <none>        6379/TCP                 16d